# Is $k[x,y]=k(y)[x]$, where $k$ is a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Somewhere I saw that

> To show that $x^2-y^3$ is irreducible in $k[x,y]$ it suffices to show that $x^2-y^3$ is irreducible in $k(y)[x]$.

My question is what is the relation between $k[x,y]$ and $k(y)[x]$ ?

Also there is a confusion that if $k(y)$ is the smallest field containing $y$ and $k$ (by definition) then what will be the inverse of $y?$ Is it $1/y$ ?

Comment: The idea is that $k(y)[x]$ contains $k[x,y]$, so if it's irreducible in the 'larger' ring it's _certainly_ irreducible in the other.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki, are you saying that if have subring $R\subseteq S$ that $r\in R$ irreducible in $S$ implies that $r$ is irreducible in $R$? But that looks wrong, for example localize $\mathbb Z$ at prime ideal $(2)$. Then $6$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_{(2)}$, but not in $\mathbb Z$, right?

Comment: @Ennar what is the meaning of $\mathbb Z_{(2)}$? Is it $\mathbb Z/ 2 \mathbb Z$

Comment: @mathiu_lady, no, it is localization at prime ideal, i.e. $\mathbb Z_{(2)} = S^{-1}\mathbb Z$ where $S$ is multiplicative set of odd numbers.

Comment: I don't know why I complicated things, I mean we are discussing Gauss lemma here. $2X$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[X]$ but not irreducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$.

Comment: @Ennar Point! The shrinking ring of units does complicate matters for the statement in the broad, but units are the only obstruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question in the title, the two rings are different because $y$ has an inverse in $k(y)[x]$ but not in $k[x,y]$.

Comment: In fact, all non-zero elements of $k(y)$  have inverses. It is a field.

Answer (score 2):

We have the following: $$k[x,y]\cong k[y][x]\subseteq k(y)[x],$$ since $k[y]\subseteq k(y)$ because $k(y)=Frac(k[y])$.

Now, for simplicity let's set $k[y]=R$, then we have to show that $x^2-y^3$ is irreducible in $R[x]$. By [Gauss' lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)) it's enough to show that $x^2-y^3$ is irreducible in $Frac(R)[x]=k(y)[x]$. This explains the given argument.